# Updating Category Description in Wordpress via SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to update a category's description via SQL. I "created php code" from the SQL query I did in PHPmyadmin and this is what it gave me:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table`.`wp_term_taxonomy` SET `description` = \'new-description\' WHERE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = 105;";
```

I tried adding this to my Wordpress template but it didn't work. Any ideas what I need to do to this code to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably

```
`table`
```

that doesn't belong.  Try:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `wp_term_taxonomy` SET `description` = 'new-description' WHERE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = 105";
```

I also took out the `\`s around the description, and the `;` in the string.  You don't need to escape single quotes in a double-quote delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Here is the correct code in case anyone is interested:

```
<?php
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
    SET description = 'description'
    WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 105
    "
);
?>
```